# Synchronize with calendar from Outlook

Tags: office-365, outlook, sharepoint-calendar

I want to be able to view my calendar from Microsoft Outlook in SharePoint (Office 365). Of course, it should synchronize, so that all updates from made in Outlook are shown in SharePoint.

When I click in SharePoint on "Calendars -> Connect to Outlook", I can see my calendar from SharePoint in Outlook. However, I want it the other way round: Outlook -> SharePoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using Calendar Overlays.

Open the Calendar view, then click on "Calendar" from Ribbon. Then choose "Calendars Overlay".

This will bring up the overlay screen, here you can click on "New Calendar".

In the settings screen you can enter

1. Calendar Name
2. Then choose "Exchange"
3. Enter Outlook Web Access URL
4. Enter Exchange Web Service URL
5. Click Find, then choose the Calendar. Click OK.

Comment: Thank you. Could you also briefly explain, where to find Outlook Web Access URL and Exchange Web Service URL?

Comment: Is your exchange on premise?